# Installing socket.io C++

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, socket.io

I try to work with socket.io in C++ but I can't seem to get the example running.
First it asked me to convert the project to my visual studio (which is 2015). So I did that. Then it was missing libraries offcourse (boost, websocket++, rapidjson). So I added them to the additional libraries in the project settings. Then it was searching for boost.lib. Boost.lib doesnt exist in the boost library I installed on my pc, so I deleted it from the dependency list. I figured I already included boost, why would it search for a lib that doesn't exist. I ran bjam.exe and b2.exe etc from boost, so if there would be a boost.lib it should be there I guess and it isn't.

I then got this error: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z.aspx
So I added msvcrt.lib and msvcmrt.lib to the linker's Additional Dependencies property. Which caused the errors in the included image..

Now all the steps seemed to fix the problems I had, but also create more errors in the process. I do not understand how to run a project like this and I can't find a good explanation of the steps I need to take.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp

That is what I try to run, the included SioChatExample

Thanks for any help in advance!

Current errors..... :(
[image: errors...]

Comment: have you tried using the cmake version to configure this? this should take a lot of work (for configuring things manually) from you.

Comment: I didn't know about that, I will have a look at it!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i think many errors because of `VC++` version.
creator of project `Socket.io-c++`, he used `VC++ 11.0`
if you use `VC++ 14.0` to build it, you will get the error. for suggestion you should use `VC++ 12.0`

**In cast you want to use prebuilt libraries:**

i myself just try many solutions,
goodness i fix all

you can get them here [Prebuilt-libraries-for-Socket.io-c++](https://github.com/raksa/SocketIO-cpp-lib)

for Visual Studio 2015, what u need are:

- install more `Visual Studio 2013` (i install `Visual Studio 2013 community`) to get `VC++ 12.0` (prebuilt-lib is built in `VC++ 12.0`)
- change your project Platform Toolset to Visaul Studio 2013 (v120)
- link libraries to your project

libraries you need are:

> libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_50.lib
>
> libboost_random-vc120-mt-gd-1_50.lib
>
> libboost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_50.lib
>
> sioclient.lib

include folder of *.h (header of `Socket.io-C++`) to your project

build and run