# How to add 3rd party library in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, socket.io, unreal-engine4

I am new to Unreal Engine. But here is what I planned to do. I want to an experiment project by combining socket.io with Unreal Engine 4. I know somebody may shot at me, for it already had a plugin. But I don't like graph programming at all (I prefer "real" coding)

But as I followed instruction from [Installing socket.io C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368295/installing-socket-io-c) and [here](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/How_to_Link_External_C_Libraries_.dll_.lib_With_Your_Project_%26_Package_With_Game,_Fast_And_Easy). It just won't work. The error told me something about `File Not Found` on multiple headers file from [this github repo](https://github.com/raksa/SocketIO-cpp-lib). So I tried to add a lot of things (Hopefully it won't affect the  outcome). And now a tons of errors had popped up. Now they are mostly about `Macro errors`. And I have absolutely no idea how to fix.

The problem is I don't understand why after I include `.lib` files to `PublicAdditionalLibraries` I still needed the original file (Shouldn't it work like any other visual studio projects?)

Also how to tackle loads of errors I am facing

Thanking in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add your include paths with the lib headers to `PublicIncludePaths` array ( in the `StartupModule()` method ? it's gonna be needed to use methods from your lib.

Here is an exemple how to use the `PublicIncludePaths`

`string includePath = Path.Combine(ThirdPartyPath, "opencv", "include");
PublicIncludePaths.Add(includePath);`

`ThirdPartyPath` is a member of my module class i retrieve with my getter
`Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(ModulePath, "../../ThirdParty/"));`

I took a look at the github repo of Socket-IO-cpp lib and the only libs compiled for windows are in 32bits, take care you're not tried to compile in 64bits, or every .lib files of your libraries are in 32bits to be linked all together, in case you're using others libs.

If you got some runtime error, take a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172258/runtime-error-when-referencing-external-library-in-unreal-engine/49303940#49303940) which explain how to indicate .dll when .libs arn't enough.

Hope it helps

Comment: Apparently, I did not include `PublicIncludePaths` array. Now it works like charmed! Thanks